# ios Send Latitude and Longitude to WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I use location manager in my app to get Latitude and Longitude:

```
double latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
double longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

In this same view controller, I load a WebView:

```
NSString *URL = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com"];
NSURL *urlDisplay = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlDisplay];
[_mainWebView loadRequest:urlDisplay];
```

My question is: how can I pass my latitude and longitude to the WebView for use when the page loads. I need to alter the information displayed in the WebView based on the users location.

Comment: That entirely depends on how the HTML takes the coordinates.  Is it expecting parameters attached to the URL?  or are the coordinates meant to be sent in a cookie?  or?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking. I need to use the coordinates in my web php file. What's the best way to get them there?

Comment: will the web page be continually updating or could you just pass in coordinates when the page is first loaded?

Comment: just the initial load

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I've misunderstood your question ... are you merely asking how to pass latitude and longitude to a URL for use in a webview. That is pretty easy (and not particularly iOS related).

With Google Maps you can search by Latitude and Longitude by using a URL search string like this:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.661383,-79.390862
```

If you wanted to use Bing Maps the same thing would be:

```
http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?cp=43.661383~-79.390862
```

(The location is Queen's Park in Toronto.) More information about geoSearching with Bing is located here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx

If you wanted to use another service, just figure how how their search string works. So if you wanted to open up a Google Maps web page you could use something like this:

```
NSArray *geoLocation = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:latitude, longitude, nil];
NSString *searchString = [geoLocation componentsJoinedByString:@","]; 
NSString *google = @"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=";
NSString *URL = [google stringByAppendingString:searchString];
NSURL *urlDisplay = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
```

By the way - If you only want to display a map by geo location you could use MapKit .... but I am sure you already know that and want to do something different.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I capture the latitude and longitude from the Location Manager in iOS, and I need to send that to the WebView before it loads.

Comment: I'm not clear (and it seems others as well) on what you mean by "send that to the WebView before it loads". The code I wrote above CAN be used to pass the latitude and longitude to the WebView before it loads, if what you want to do is pass PHP variables within a URL. I am not sure on how/why else you would want to pass variables to a UIWebView?